# What option in XCode needs to be changed

Tags: xcode

ALL,
I'm working with XCode 4.2 on Snow Leopard to build a custom application. It is not intended to be put on the Apple Store.
The question I have is: what option I need to change in order to place the resulting bundle in my home directory and not to the XCode default place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations.

There you can change the path of the derived data. You can change the location of all your projects' derived data or use the Advanced option to be able to set the location for your targets separately using target settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the nicely explained info.